# Gradle ignores daemon ignore flag

Tags: java, gradle, java-9

I'm running Gradle `3.2.1` on MacOS X 10.12.1 installed with `brew install gradle`, did not set any env variables etc. myself, trying to use the Java 9 EA:

```
gradle build -Dorg.gradle.java.home=~/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home
```

But the build is failing with

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Unable to start the daemon process. This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon. For example,
>     an unrecognized jvm option is used.

From what I know it fails because the daemon is trying to use the maxpermsize JVM option (which is not supported in Java 8+ but in Java 8 it's only a warning).

So I tried to disable the daemon:

```
mkdir -p ~/.gradle && echo "org.gradle.daemon=false" >> ~/.gradle/gradle.properties
```

But `gradle build` is still trying to start a daemon... I removed `~/.gradle` and `.gradle` in the project directory. Any other ideas?

```
$ gradle build -Dorg.gradle.daemon=false -Dorg.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/3.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/3.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Starting Daemon%
```

Comment: Is GRADLE_OPTS env variable set? Also GRADLE_USER_HOME variable effects location where gradle looks for properties file...? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

Comment: @Adam neither of those variables are set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out, since I'm running my build like this:

```
gradle build -Dorg.gradle.java.home=~/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Gradle has to spawn a new thread to use a different Java version than the one pointed to by JAVA_HOME. This is done by spawning a daemon thread (even despite the `false` option) with that Java version and is failing. The same would happen if I passed JVM args to the build apparently.

The solution is to instead set JAVA_HOME in the terminal `export JAVA_HOME=~/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home` and just run `gradle build`.

Still doesn't work because the newest Java9 build broke Gradle's reflection but that's a different story.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this here since it's too big of a comment (but it is for sure not an answer).

If you run your script with **--debug** you will see the underlying error. I am running this directly via java-9 without setting the JAVA_HOME btw.

I had the same issue a few jdk-9 builds back and tackled it with:

```
 set _JAVA_OPTIONS "-Dsun.reflect.debugModuleAccessChecks=true 
             --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED 
             --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED 
             --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED 
             --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED 
             --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED 
             --add-opens=java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED"
```

**set** instead of **export** because I'm using fish, but should work for bash the same way.

Interestingly enough this still fails with build 153 with this:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.Map java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.m accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @67080771
```

But that is specified within _JAVA_OPTIONS. This might be a regression on build 153.

Comment: Hey @Eugene, my original issue was with gradle starting a daemon thread even though I specified not to (which was complaining about a redundant JVM parameter) but as it turns out if you pass `org.gradle.java.home` or `org.gradle.jvmargs` as `-D` then gradle works that way and it's to be expected. Your answer seems to help with running Gradle+Java9, which is a bit of a different issue I'm having now :-)

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk yeah.. I know. I *king of* predicted you will eventually hit the same issue I did

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk can you still run your gradle invocation btw? Cause I can't with the settings i showed in my answer/comment

Comment: I see, thanks! But yeah, as you noticed there's a new problem (the `module java.base does not ...`), which is an open issue in Gradle's github repository so I guess I need to skip Gradle and do all the stuff manually :-/

Comment: no, unfortunately it's on the roadmap https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1095

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk the work-around posted there seems to not work as I have shown. This *could* be jdk related thing...

Comment: hm yes, they might've changed something in the newest JDK, anyway I don't think Gradle folks will pay to it much attention just now since those are only early release versions :-(